# Center the current table row on a overflowing table using $autoScroll without yOffset

Tags: angularjs, css, css-selectors

I have a table which is overflowing and I could make the table autoScroll to current element which was based on time using angular $location.hash(#elementID) and $anchorScroll service. However I couldn't apply yOffset to $anchorScroll as the scroll element was not document root element as in angular documentation.Is there any way I could center the current table row using CSS3 properties or any other suggestion is welcome. I tried using angular element JQlite offset property also CSS margin-top but they didn't work.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

HTML

```
<html>
  <div> </div> ...
  <div id="contentControl" ng-controller="TableController as TableCtrl">   
   <table> 
      <tr id="$index">   </tr>
      <tr id="$index">   </tr>
      <tr id="$index">   </tr>
      <tr id="TestID">   </tr>
      ....
      <tr id="$index">   </tr>
      <tr id="$index">   </tr>
      ...
    </table>
   </div>
</html>
```

My angular Code inside a controller function

```
angular.module("testmodule").controller("TableController",TableController);
//tableCenterPos is a constant with in my angular module.
function TableController($anchorScroll,$location,$scope,tableCenterPos) {

    $scope.ScrollToCurrentAppt = function() {
         $location.hash("TestID");
         $anchorScroll();
         // After this step I was able to see my table row as first row;
         // Now I want position my table such that my table row will appear as center to table instead of first row .

          $anchorScroll.yOffset = tableCenterPos; //This didnt work.

    }

}
```

Comment: No one can help you unless you have a conceptual non-code-specific question or you post code with your question. You fall under the latter. Please post code.

Comment: @Rorschach120 : Added the code.